# How to detect end of a download call in swift

Tags: xcode, download, swift4, xcode10

I am using a class to handle my download functionality. When I am done downloading data for multiple items such as sound and pictures, how should I inform the class controlling the view that the downloads are done?

Comment: You would have a completion handler for the download call. You should notify the view from there.

Comment: I am able to process data in the completion handler for the service call, is there a way not to use notifications to call other functions which will use the data downloaded